# Automatic Configuration Generation

Tags: python, scripting, firewall

I am installing Cisco ASA Firewall for my customer at several locations. The basic ASA configuration for all the locations is the same with a deviation of certain things like Interface IP addresses, Routing next hops, etc.

For every location I have an excel sheet with all the variables.

I know basic Python. The question is : is it possible to write a script in python which will read the variables in the Excel Sheet and generate the configuration for ASA?

Moreover could someone recommend a source to learn scripting targeted for networking or such an automation task? (Simply googling led me to many confusing options and hence the question here)

Comment: Could you provide an example of the Excel file in CSV format along with an example of what the configuration file might look like?

Comment: Again off topic? I put this same question on Stack Exchange's Networking Engineering page. There it was tagged as off topic with the suggestion that this question is suitable for stackoverflow since it involves programming.  I dont understand where to ask such questions then ! :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you use templating engine such as jinja2 along with python.
(https://github.com/jedelman8/interop-nyc-2014.git)
(http://keepingitclassless.net/2014/03/network-config-templates-jinja2/)

Or you can use simple Ansible tool along with Jinja2 templates to generate configs. (No need for programming skills)
(https://sreeninet.wordpress.com/2014/09/28/ansible-for-networking-automation-part-1/)
(https://sreeninet.wordpress.com/2014/09/28/ansible-for-network-automation-part-2/)
(https://sreeninet.wordpress.com/2014/09/28/network-device-configuration-using-templates-with-jinja2-and-yaml/)
(http://jedelman.com/home/ansible-for-networking/)

I would also suggest to look at a very good library "netmiko" for ssh connection in future and push, pull config (https://github.com/ktbyers/netmiko/tree/master/examples)

All above options can work for you. See below examples. I am a Network professional myself and found these useful.

Comment: Thanks a lot M.W.A.!! Will try all the links!

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty easily done with Python, but will take a bit of learning.

Depending on the format of the Excel file, I would recommend [OpenPyXL](https://encrypted.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjLqY3s2KTKAhXJ6CYKHVkfDywQFggcMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fopenpyxl.readthedocs.org%2F&usg=AFQjCNGwv3TdwNTcRMot6XgyM_KPx8RD4A), or [XLRD](https://encrypted.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiKwcDp2KTKAhWM4yYKHZaqAVYQFggcMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fpypi.python.org%2Fpypi%2Fxlrd&usg=AFQjCNEAk71dm3HPf9QoT-2gXfmoCHwNSw).

This will also depend on the configuration format you are wanting to output. If it's a JSON Config file, you can simple use the built-in [json](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) module. Otherwise, there are a variety of other modules out there for things like CSV, etc.

One warning, however. If you hard-code all of your Excel columns/positions within your code, you could be in for a world of hurt in the event that the columns change.

Comment: Thanks a lot disflux!!